# drupal_mail and drupal_send_email don't work?

Tags: email, drupal-6

My situation is as follows:

I use ubercart and I have 3 modules installed for email (when a customer makes the purchase) confirmation of a purchase. The modules are: SMTP, MIMEMail and HTML MAIL.
Verifying, sending works with HTML.
However, I need to make another type of email, when a product expires.
And that I'm doing with my own module. However, when I use the function of drupal_mail or drupal_mail_send sending doesn't correct.
When I debug the function apparently everything is correct, but I don't get any email.

My code for the function is drupal_mail_send:

```
$message = array(
    'to' => $to,
    'from' => $from,
    'id' => 'cuponalcubo_mailing',
    'subject' => $subject,
    'body' => $body,
    'headers' => array(
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => '8Bit',
        'X-Mailer' => 'Pressflow',
    )
);
drupal_mail_send($message);
```

And the code for the function is drupal_mail:

```
function ....(){
$params = array(
        'subject' => $subject,
        'body' => t($body)
    );
    drupal_mail('email_deal_vp', 'email_deal_vp_html_mail', $to, language_default(), $params, $from);
}

/*
 * Implements HOOK_MAIL
 */
function email_deal_vp_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    $language = $message['language'];
    switch ($key) {
        case 'email_deal_vp_html_mail':
            $message['subject'] = t($params['subject'], $var, $language->language);
              $body = "<html><body>
                  {$params['body']}
                  </body></html>";
              $message['body'][] = $body;
              $message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
              break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look in your spam folder?  Do you have access to the logs on the mail server you connect to?

Comment: In my spam folder i don't have any email. And in the log of the mail server, all emails don't send.

Comment: What are the error messages in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a problem with your server (SMTP is not configured properly). Check with any existing mail code whether it is working. (If it was working before.)

Comment: The problem was for the server mail!! >.<

Comment: Thank for all! :D. Now my other problem is send email with html. I use a TPL but don't load the style u.u